# Transform type of functions into the return type of those functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
type AllLoaders = {
  usersLoader: () => DataLoader<string, User[]>;
  imagesLoader: () => DataLoader<string, Image[]>;
};
```

Is it possible to transform it into this?

```
type Loaders = {
  usersLoader: DataLoader<string, User[]>;
  imagesLoader: DataLoader<string, Image[]>;
};
```

So I don't have to manually define each *loader* property.

I am aware of the [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) utility type, but I am not able to "iterate" over the `AllLoaders` type properties to apply it for each type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a [mapped typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).

```js
// Stubs for types not provided
type DataLoader<T, U> = {};
type User = {};
type Image = {};

// The type you provided
type AllLoaders = {
  usersLoader: () => DataLoader<string, User[]>;
  imagesLoader: () => DataLoader<string, Image[]>;
};

type Input = {
  [index: string]: (...args: any) => any;
};

// Define the most "general" accepted shape as the input generic.
// Without this, the ReturnType errors:
// Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
type Transform<T extends Input> = { [Key in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[Key]> };

type Result = Transform<AllLoaders>;
// type Result = {
//     usersLoader: DataLoader<string, User[]>;
//     imagesLoader: DataLoader<string, Image[]>;
// }
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEGUBcFcCMGdQDMD2AnUkCeAHApogHYqSg5ooBuAlgCZ60BQ2+oAIgIaQcAyKH9NAB4AKgBpQAVQB8oALygA3gF8A3M1x4p8PBgUr1LLQEkAthwDmW-WsaMQoEQAstR0FhTQyFGvSZuAQQAbIL4BXUR9RlBQaB00eDDBAC5QAAoASnlZTm4k3SF4SDRqQgsJSXiAbQBdaXUY6nMrRP4U9Ky5HK5eNoKikrKJM0s8WvrGWw1WY0IcaFIomKrS+gAPVIHSixrUtIA6Q440C3hUjkIsTtkLrHUphzY8JFLXF1BTFCLQACIrQl0HCCP1AHAAxmC8DhIAxQPAnBxWBxEJB3qV5qR-rpqGD9vYwAB1aiozykVHUeASVFaABKeBgaEIIk0oF0FASyXxjhZAHIRFUtmUajzQBTQMRSMj4NQLIQOLAgq4UJheQcjiczqDLtctVgeXi3CI0Bd4Kg0KZRKy1jDCLRELMMbJ9KAqgBpPBYUWEUAAaw9KCQjl2oDpDKZmlEbo9dVAUzcdPg0CCi0cxsIpvQFuCoT6CQmDnjBCTKcUXJiMTiEXyaFSuV64WEgvK2l043UDnLouaBGrtZ61cKxW2w27ba5ykYQA)